# Есть ли у русского языка официальный словарь?

Tags: словарь

Существует ли у русского языка единый официальный, "авторитетный" (толковый, и не только) словарь?

В рунете ясного ответа не нашёл, кроме [этой древненькой статейки](https://www.newsru.com/russia/31aug2009/slovari.html).

Какое состояние дел на 2022 год?

Comment: что вы подразумеваете под официальным - что он нормирует что? Это толковый словарь - что значит и не только?  орфоэпический? тезаурус?

Comment: А чем вас не устраивают словари из этой древней статейки?

Answer (score 3):

> Какое состояние дел на 2022 год?

В справочниках правовой информации (гарант.ру, консультант.ру) тот приказ считается действующим. Т.е. он не отменён и другой более актуальной редакции нет.

> Существует ли у **русского языка** единый официальный, "авторитетный" [...]

Обратите внимание, что действие того приказа распространяется не на весь русский язык, а только на использование русского языка **в качестве государственного языка РФ**. Т.е. в нормативных актах, в делопроизводстве и т.п., но не в литературе и в речи.

А что касается языка в целом, так существует Институт русского языка им. Виноградова, входящий в структуру РАН. Посмотрите в сторону его публикаций и публикаций, которые им признаются авторитетными:

- https://orfo.ruslang.ru/
- http://gramota.ru/slovari/info/